# Changing source directories in sbt shell

Tags: sbt

I'd like to change source directories for my test files but only temporarily in current session. I tried the following:

```
> scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-src"

[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: scalaSource
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '::'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-src"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sbt shell, you need to use the [`set` command](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Command-Line-Reference.html#commands-for-managing-the-build-definition) to apply changes to the settings of the current project:

```
> set scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-src"
```

You can then use `session save` if you want to persist them to your `build.sbt`.

Comment: Settings are vals once sbt's up and any change to their values requires `reload` implicitly (`set`) or explicitly (`reload`).